# How to take the integral of the following

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int\sqrt{16x^2+8+\frac 1{x^2}}\,\mathrm d x$$

I tried various substitutions, including trig functions (to see if I could do it the way I would do $\int\sqrt{1+x^2}\,\mathrm d x$), but didn't get an answer.  How would I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Try learning [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts here. Also, it would be more useful to show your work- whatever you have done.

Comment: Hint: $$16x^2+8+\frac 1{x^2}=\left(4x+\frac1x\right)^2\implies\sqrt{16x^2+8+\frac 1{x^2}}=\left|4x+\frac1x\right|$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT, substitute $u=x^2$ and $\text{d}u=2x\space\text{d}x$:

$$\mathcal{I}(x)=\int\sqrt{16x^2+8+\frac{1}{x^2}}\space\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{\sqrt{16x^4+8x^2+1}}{x}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{16u^2+8u+1}}{u}\space\text{d}u=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\sqrt{(1+4u)^2}}{u}\space\text{d}u$$

Answer (score -1):

Try the hyperbolic substitution $x=sinh(y)$

Comment: Sorry but did you try it yourself before recommending it?

Comment: I did not see the function, I was giving a tip on how to solve $\sqrt{1+x^2}$